# Silverlight (4.0) for WPF users

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

For years I have exclusively worked with WPF and never touched Silverlight. Is there a quick tour for WPF pros that introduces me to Silverlight (4.0) its unique features and its differences to WPF?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pls, see if links below would be useful for you

[Contrasting Silverlight and WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458872.aspx)

[Silverlight 4 Beta Information](http://silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight-4-beta/#whatsnew)

[Silverlight Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404713(VS.95).aspx)

Comment: The first link is excellent, just added it to my bookmarks ;)

Comment: The first link seems to be extremely out of date, since it referes to silverlight 2.0. A lot of the differences seem to be eliminated in 3.0 and 4.0.